# Unity stopped working in 3D after software update

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, updates

Today I installed some update package and an hour or two later when I restarted my machine, Unity was running in 2D. There were two Radeon packs in those updates which I suspect are the culprit. I attempted to purge the fglrx completely and do a fresh install of the AMD drivers (currently running with AMD HD 7400m gpu and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) but I did not manage to purge it. Does anyone have any suggestions? Million thank yous in advance!

Comment: **32-bit** or **64-bit** Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ?

Comment: 64-bit, sorry, I forgot to mention that part. What I have managed to figure out so far is that I installed a third party PPA for my video card and those repositories were either corrupted or not meant for my kernel, so I removed them via Synaptic. Unfortunately, that removed some of the files needed to uninstall the video drivers, so now I am unable to do that.

Comment: Repeat the install, to get them back. Then **purge** the PPA you added, and run updates. If needed run **`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`**

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, for some reason I was completely unable to install or remove any type of software due to broken packages - as I later found out, synaptic was unable to actually repair the pack or remove it completely. At that point I decided to just go along with a fresh install of Ubuntu. Once again, thanks for your time and effort! Peace.